# Named anchor getting covered by menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use named anchors with a sticky Bootstrap menu (class `navbar-fixed-top`). My issue is that when the user clicks on an anchor link, e.g.

```
<a href="#anchor1">goto anchor 1</a>
```

the browser will scroll down so that `#anchor1` is at the top of the page, but the top of the page is covered by my sticky menu. I need someway to have the browser scroll up on menu height from the anchor. How can I fix this? Also, I expect some links coming from outside my site to also point to named anchors, e.g.

```
<!-- Link on someone else's website I can't control -->
<a href="https://exampel.com/mypage.html#anchor1">goto section 1</a>
```

Comment: Did you add padding-top to the body as per Bootstrap's documentation?

Comment: @RachelS Yes, I do have padding-top to the body. It doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Where is your code?